# Multiple url rewrite rule iis express

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I would like to achieve that rewrite all request like something.mypage.hu/some or otherthing.nypage.hu
to an ip address.

But I want to rewrite the nuget.mypage.hu to another ip address.

How should I create the rules?

If I use only the first rule

````
          ```<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*).somepage.hu(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://SOMEIP:5000/{R:1}/{R:2}" />```
````

It works fine. I just can't get another rule working for nuget.mypage.hu that points on a different IP address.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*).somepage.hu(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://SOMEIP:5000/{R:1}/{R:2}" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^nuget.somepage.hu(.*)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)nuget.somepage.hu(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost/nuget/{R:1}" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(.*)nuget.somepage.hu(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Calling the url-s just not rewriting any calls.

Comment: Mistake 1 https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: is this nuget.mypage.hu hostname or the file path? if it is hostname use {http_host} in the condition in the first URL rewrite rule and check the entered URL and the value used in url rewrite rule patter is the correct.

Comment: That is the hostname.

Comment: REQUEST_URI returns the absolute part of the URI. e.g. https://contoso.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret would return /over/there. if you want to match the hostname you need to use {HTTP_HOST}. for more information, you could refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-dev-reference/server-variables)